# How to display success message in minicart after add to cart shopify?

Tags: ajax, api, shopify, minicart

I want to show success message after add to cart.

Please check screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Need to update the code into mini cart, and desired functionality.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.